# reconnecting app to debug after unplugging USB cable

Tags: android, debugging

Is there a way to continue debugging with Eclipse after the USB cable has been disconnected.

The app is started in debug mode, the USB cable is disconnected, and then connected again.
Now I like to continue the debugging.
Is this possible without restarting the app?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go in DDMS perspective and look in Devices view for your device. Scroll the list of running applications and find yours. Select it and click the first button in toolbar - the green bug. Eclipse will now attach to the running process and you'll continue from the current state.